Analyticity of $f*g$ with $f$ and $g$ smooth on $\mathbb{R}$ and analytic on $\mathbb{R}^*$
Suppose that we have two real functions $f$ and $g$ both belonging to $\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ analytic on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ but non-analytic at $x=0$. Is the convolution (assumed to be well defined) defined as:
$$(f*g)(x) = \int_\mathbb{R}f(x-z)g(z)dz$$
an analytic function ?
Otherwise, under which conditions the convolution is analytic ?
Any references or solutions will be highly appreciated.

Have a look at the properties of the Fourier transform of analytic functions at MO23679. If you pick your functions to be analytic at least in some strip around the real axis, I suspect that the answer will come out: iff one of $f$ or $g$ is analytic.

Thank you @IgorKhavkine for the post you mentinned. A quick question, when it is mentionned "the fourier transform should decay exponentially", we are talking about the module of the fourier tranform ?.
It is to say that if $|\mathcal{F}f*g| < e^{-a|u|}$ for some $a>0$, $f*g$ is analytic ?

The precise condition quoted in the answer by Nate Eldredge uses the $L^2$-norm on the shifted real axis. Consult the cited reference for more details. More specialized literature might give analogous results with different norms.

@IgorKhavkine: $\mathbb{R}$ has two "ends", I can easily imagine a situation where $f$ has exponential decay on one end and $g$ on the other.

@WillieWong Ah yes, a perfectly valid point!

Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4940919/analycity-of-fg-with-f-and-g-smooth-on-mathbbr-and-analytic-on-mat

The answer to your question is negative. Take the smooth function $\chi$ defined by
$$
\chi(t)=H(t) e^{-t^{-1}-t^2}, \quad H=\mathbf 1_{(0,+\infty)}.
$$
This function is in $L^1(\mathbb R)$, $C^\infty$ everywhere, analytic outside $0$, and not analytic at $0$, in fact flat at $0$, i.e. all derivatives are vanishing at 0. Let us define $F=\chi\ast\chi$; we have $F\in L^1(\mathbb R)$,
$F$ is $C^\infty$ everywhere, and for $k\in \mathbb N$,
$$
F^{(k)}(t)=\int\chi^{(k)}(t-s)\chi(s) ds,
$$
so that
$
F^{(k)}(0)=\int\chi^{(k)}(-s)\chi(s) ds=0,
$
since $s$ must be non-negative and non-positive in the integrand. So the function $F$ is flat at $0$ and is positive for $t>0$, so cannot be analytic at $0$.

Thank you for this great answer @Bazin! Do you have any idea for the case $\chi_1(t) = H(t)e^{-1/t-t^2}$, $\chi_2(t) = H(-t)e^{-1/|t|-t^2}$ ($\chi_2$ being the symetric of $\chi_1$ w.r.t. $y$-axis) and $F=\chi_1*\chi_2$ ?

@NancyBoy I guess that this new $F$ is not analytic, but that the proof is not as simple as for $\chi\ast\chi$ in my answer. In fact the product of the Fourier transforms of your functions $\chi_j$ cannot be exponentially decreasing. Maybe my post "Fourier transform of Analytic Functions" (see the linked posts above on the right) may help understand that business further.
